# Joule-Thomson effect of Van der Waals gas

Tags: homework-and-exercises, thermodynamics

I'm supposed to calculate the inversion pressure $p_i$ of a [Van der Waals gas](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Van_der_Waals_gas). The state equation of the Van der Waals gas is: $$(p + \frac{a}{V^2})(V-b) = RT.$$ To get a hold of the inversion temperature, I differentiate this equation with respect to $T$, while keeping $p$ constant. This gives me:
$$\frac{(\frac{\partial V}{\partial T})_p \cdot (2ab - aV + pV^3)}{V^3} = R,$$ which with the condition for the inversion curve $T(\frac{\partial V}{\partial T})_p = V$ I get:
$$\frac{1}{T_i}(\frac{2ab}{V^2} - \frac{a}{V} + pV) = R,$$ which gives me an easy to solve equation for $T_i$. But to get $p_i$, I'd have to solve the equation for $V$ and put it back into the state equation. But solving this equation for $V$ gets really messy. That's why I'm thinking I went wrong somewhere.

Can you guys help me out here?

Comment: You might find the following link usefull - it describe how to obtain the inversion curve for a VDW gas. http://employees.csbsju.edu/cgearhart/Courses/Thermal/Lecture/van_der_Waals.pdf

Answer (score 1):

Solve Van der Waal's equation and approximate the $PV$ term by $RT$, and you will have  your required equation. Although we are introducing an error, it will hardly affect the final result since there will be both $a$ and $b$.

For Van der Waal gas: 
$$\left(p+\frac{n^2q}{v^2}\right)\left(v-nb\right) = nRT$$
$$\Rightarrow pv+\frac{n^2q}{v}-pnb-\frac{n^3ab}{v^2}=nRT$$
$$\Rightarrow pv = nRT - \frac{n^2q}{v}+pnb+\frac{n^3ab}{v^L}$$
$$\Rightarrow V = \frac{nRT}{p} - \frac{n^2q}{pV}+nb+\frac{n^3ab\cdot P}{pV^2\cdot P}$$
$$\Rightarrow V = \frac{nRT}{P}-\frac{nq}{RT}+nb+\frac{nabP}{R^2T^2}$$
Note: Replacing $Pv$ by $nRT$ in the terms, the error becomes negligibly small and it hardly affects the final result.
$$\because \left(\frac{\partial V}{\partial T}\right)_p = \frac{nR}{P}+\frac{nq}{RT^2}-\frac{2nabP}{R^2T^3}$$
We know, then, that $$M_{JT}=\left(\frac{\partial T}{\partial P}\right)_H$$
$$\Rightarrow M_{JT}=-\frac{1}{cp}\left(\frac{\partial H}{\partial P}\right)_T = -\frac{1}{cp}\left[V-\left(\frac{\partial V}{\partial T}\right)_P T\right]$$

---

Note from editor: some of the handwriting was a bit unclear, so here is the original picture posted for reference (I did, however, rotate the image so it is easier to read):

[image]

Comment: Hi and welcome to physics.SE! Please write answers in complete English sentences, not textspeak. Also, instead of posting a picture, please typeset equations with [MathJax](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference)

Comment: There are many errors in the equations in terms of using $v$ and $V$ interchangingly, please correct it. Also an exponent "L" should be replaced by "2".